# [Solved]How to make my stepper motor run clockwise and counterclockwise?

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm relatively new to Arduino thus need your help to figure out why my stepper motor doesn't rotate clockwise and counterclockwise. All I could do was to make it rotate only in one direction.

I am using AccelStepper Library

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <AccelStepper.h>
//Define stepper motor connections
#define dirPin 4
#define stepPin 14
//Create stepper object
AccelStepper stepper(1,stepPin,dirPin); //motor interface type must be set to 1 when using a driver.
void setup()
{
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1200); //maximum steps per second
}
void loop()
{
  stepper.setSpeed(1200); //steps per second
  stepper.runSpeed(); //step the motor with constant speed as set by setSpeed()
}
```

I have tried to add delay and counterclockwise code but its not working.

```cpp
#include <AccelStepper.h>
//Define stepper motor connections
#define dirPin 4
#define stepPin 14
//Create stepper object
AccelStepper stepper(1,stepPin,dirPin); //motor interface type must be set to 1 when using a driver.
void setup()
{
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1200); //maximum steps per second
}
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  stepper.setSpeed(1200); //steps per second
  stepper.runSpeed(); //step the motor with constant speed as set by setSpeed()
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("counterclockwise");
  stepper.setSpeed(-1200); //steps per second
  stepper.runSpeed(); //step the motor with constant speed as set by setSpeed()
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Try to use lower values for spinning, let's say 150. Some drivers are easy overheating when using higher speeds.

Comment: `it rotate only in one direction` ... which direction is that?

Comment: No its not about heating or higher speed

If i put 1200 it move perfectly clockwise if i put value to -1200 it move perfectly counter-clockwise 

But if i try to use both it creates problem

Comment: What hardware do you use? I mean, what is the stepper motor driver? There are some drivers which overheat easily and (due to built-in overheat protection) stop operation.

Comment: @smajli its not about heating
i am missing something with code
if i rotate in 1 direction only with default code it works fine. 
Motor - NEMA17 5.5Kgcm Stepper Motor

Answer (score 2):

Hi here it the reference to the library functions that are available in [accelstepper library](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/classAccelStepper.html).

Go through the link, it will provide you the issues with your code and example for your application like @smajli said **steps more than 1000 is unreliabe**, here you can see `setSpeed(float)` function where setting negative or positive sign selects the direction and value set the speed of rotation.

Comment: than you for your input but i am still struggling to understand functions :(
i have changed speed to 1000 and behavior is still same

Comment: did you tried -500 and 500 ?

Comment: yes buddy seems i can't use delay function in loop but i am not getting how to use other function of this library or use millis function

Answer (score 0):

From the AccelStepper website: [link](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/classAccelStepper.html#ae79c49ad69d5ccc9da0ee691fa4ca235)

> Speeds of more than 1000 steps per second are unreliable

Try to change the speed to lower value, and let us know what is the outcome.

Comment: thank you for pointing out but still same behavior